# TypeError: ratio() missing 1 required positional argument: 'metric_fun'

Tags: python, aif360

I'm trying to use the aif360 library of ibm for debiasing.
I'm working on a linear regression model and want to try out a metric to calculate the difference between the priviliged and unpriviliged groups.
However when this code is run I get the following error:

TypeError: difference() missing 1 required positional argument: 'metric_fun'

I've looked into the class for this function but they are referring to a metric_fun, also read the docs but didn't get any further.
The function is missing an argument, but I don't know which argument it expects.

A short snippit of the code is:

```
train_pp_bld = StructuredDataset(df=pd.concat((x_train, y_train),
                                                axis=1),
                                  label_names=['decile_score'],
                                  protected_attribute_names=['sex_Male'],
                                  privileged_protected_attributes=1,
                                  unprivileged_protected_attributes=0)

privileged_groups = [{'sex_Male': 1}]
unprivileged_groups = [{'sex_Male': 0}]

# Create the metric object
metric_train_bld = DatasetMetric(train_pp_bld,
                                            unprivileged_groups=unprivileged_groups,
                                            privileged_groups=privileged_groups)

# Metric for the original dataset
metric_orig_train = DatasetMetric(train_pp_bld, 
                                              unprivileged_groups=unprivileged_groups,
                                              privileged_groups=privileged_groups)
display(Markdown("#### Original training dataset"))
print("Difference in mean outcomes between unprivileged and privileged groups = %f" % metric_orig_train.difference())
```

The stack trace that was given is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/sef/Desktop/Thesis/Python Projects/Stats/COMPAS_Debias_AIF360_Continuous_Variable.py", line 116, in <module>
    print("Difference in mean outcomes between unprivileged and privileged groups = %f" % metric_orig_train.difference())

  File "/Users/sef/opt/anaconda3/envs/AI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aif360/metrics/metric.py", line 37, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: difference() missing 1 required positional argument: 'metric_fun'
```

After creating a function:

```
def privileged_value(self, privileged=False):
    if privileged:
        return unprivileged_groups['sex_Male']
    else:
        return privileged_groups['sex_Male']

display(Markdown("#### Original training dataset"))
print("Difference in mean outcomes between unprivileged and privileged groups = %f" % metric_orig_train.difference(privileged_value))
```

still get a similar error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/sef/Desktop/Thesis/Python Projects/Stats/COMPAS_Debias_AIF360_Continuous_Variable.py", line 123, in <module>
    print("Difference in mean outcomes between unprivileged and privileged groups = %f" % metric_orig_train.difference(privileged_value))

  File "/Users/sef/opt/anaconda3/envs/AI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aif360/metrics/metric.py", line 37, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/sef/opt/anaconda3/envs/AI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aif360/metrics/dataset_metric.py", line 77, in difference
    return metric_fun(privileged=False) - metric_fun(privileged=True)

  File "/Users/youssefennali/Desktop/Thesis/Python Projects/Stats/COMPAS_Debias_AIF360_Continuous_Variable.py", line 120, in privileged_value
    return privileged_groups['sex_Male']

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction?
There are no examples available of similar code online.

Regards,

Sef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code for the library on [GitHub](https://github.com/Trusted-AI/AIF360/blob/master/aif360/metrics/dataset_metric.py#L73-L77) a reference to a function needs to be passed into `difference(self, metric_fun)`. All difference does is subtract the output of your function with `privileged=False` as the input with the output of your function with `privileged=True` as the input.

```
def difference(self, metric_fun):
    """Compute difference of the metric for unprivileged and privileged
    groups.
    """
    return metric_fun(privileged=False) - metric_fun(privileged=True)
```

Create a function like this and pass it into difference.

```
def privilege_value(privileged=False) -> int:
    if privileged:
        return unprivileged_groups[0]['sex_male']
    else:
        return privileged_groups[0]['sex_male']

metric_orig_train.difference(privilege_value)
```

Comment: Thanks Raymond. Tried it, however still got a similar error code, I've added the code and traceback to the question.

Comment: I have edited the return statements in the function to access the values in the privileged and unprivileged groups.

Answer (score 0):

Well, without knowing anything about the library you're using, the error message still seems pretty clear, especially since you only call `difference` once, like this:

```
metric_orig_train.difference()
```

The error message is telling you that you should be passing an argument in this call. The name of the argument is `metric_fun`, which suggests to me that you are supposed to pass it a function reference.

NOTE: It is possible that difference() is being called outside your code.  When you supply an error message, please always submit the stack trace that came along with it, if there is one.  Then we can see exactly where in the code the problem occurred.

Comment: Hereby the stack trace: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/sef/Desktop/Thesis/Python Projects/Stats/COMPAS_Debias_AIF360_Continuous_Variable.py", line 116, in <module>
    print("Difference in mean outcomes between unprivileged and privileged groups = %f" % metric_orig_train.difference())

  File "/Users/sef/opt/anaconda3/envs/AI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aif360/metrics/metric.py", line 37, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: difference() missing 1 required positional argument: 'metric_fun'

Comment: Please put the stack trace in your question, and format it as code.  It will look nice, instead of how it looks in a comment, which is quite unreadable.

Comment: BTW, your stack trace is just readable enough to see that it does indeed appear to be referring to the line I pointed out in my answer.

Comment: I've edited the question as you suggested. It expects an argument however it is not clear what to put there. I've checked this on read the docs but it refers to metric_fun, don't know what is meant by that. It is a package where not much about is known, so googling didn't find any solutions for this problem.